# how to increase the height of each row in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

how can i increase the height of each row in a list view my xml code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/prle"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Meetdetail1Activity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/Grey"
    android:text="@string/homelinkpropose"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/Grey"
    android:text="@string/logoutproposemeet"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/meetdetaill"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    android:textSize="@dimen/meetdettextsize" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/viewdate" />

<ListView
    style="@style/dividedListStyle"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:dividerHeight="20dp">

 </ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/viewname"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sixtn" />
```

my styles.xml page is as:

```
 </style>
<style name="dividedListStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
<item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:divider">@drawable/list_divider</item>
<item name="android:dividerHeight">20dp</item>
```

and in drawable folder i have included a xml file list_divider 
@drawable/list_divider

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:shape="line">
 <stroke 
     android:color="#8F8F8F" 
     android:dashWidth="1dp" 
     android:dashGap="20dp" />
```

but still i cannot view the whole content together a part of the content gets hiden
pls hlp me... :(. Thnx in advance

Answer (score 0):

check this:

what much of height u want just use(5/8/10/12) that in relative layout

```
android:padding="8dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the root view layout_height.

```
 android:layout_height="xxdp"
```

(I have a feeling that I don't understand the question completely, because this answer would be too simple.)